# Apps that can draw on top of the screen without permission

Tags: android, view, android-permissions

I know that in order to draw any view over other apps you have to enable this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>` permission. But I have accidentally found out that some apps have this permission enabled by default (e.g. Fabulous, Android Ultimate). How on earth is that possible?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/24/system-alert-window-now-more-hidden-than-ever.html

Comment: @CommonsWare on android O use TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY

Comment: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#cwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an app is installed via Play Store and it requests `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`, permission is granted automatically to that app.

This was introduced in Marshmallow.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Never had issues with googling smh until this.